# Using 2 different Page.BottomAppBars in Pivot

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to place 2 Page.BottomAppBars in my first app. But, it doesn't work right.

MainPage.xaml:

```
    <Grid>
    <Pivot Name="Pivot" Title="Timecard" SelectionChanged="Pivot_SelectionChanged">
        <PivotItem Header="entry">
            <local:PivotEntry />
        </PivotItem>
        <PivotItem Header="list">
            <local:PivotList />
        </PivotItem>
    </Pivot>
</Grid>
```

PivotEntry.xaml

```
    <Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar Name="AppBar" Visibility="Visible">
        <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton Name="SaveEntryButton" Click="Save_Click" Icon="Save" IsCompact="False" Label="save" />
        </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
        <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton Name="SaveEntryText" Label="save" Click="Save_Click" />
        </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

PivotList.xaml

```
    <Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar Name="AppBar" Visibility="Visible">
        <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton Name="RefreshEntriesButton" Click="Refresh_Click" Icon="Refresh" IsCompact="False" Label="refresh" />
            <AppBarButton Name="ClearEntriesButton" Click="Clear_Click" Icon="Clear" IsCompact="False" Label="clear" />
        </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
        <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton Name="RefreshEntriesText" Label="refresh" Click="Refresh_Click"/>
            <AppBarButton Name="ClearEntriesText" Label="clear" Click="Clear_Click"/>
        </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

When I swipe between pages, the BottomAppBar of `PivotList` overrides the BottomAppBar of `PivotEntry`. But, if I swipe back to `PivotEntry`, the BottomAppBar of `PivotList` stays. I expected that the BottomAppBar of `PivotEntry` would reappear!

What's wrong? Please, help me!

Comment: I have the same problem